# Passing string as a var and var value in Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, return-value, var

I am just wondering if it is possible to pass a string as a var and var value in Ajax. For example:

```
var name = 'Josh';
var last = 'Williams';

var string = 'name:name, last:last'

$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'ajax.php',
  data: {string}
});
```

Comment: Not in the way you are presenting but you can stringify a JSON

Comment: That is what i am trying to figure out. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: `var string = {"name": name, "last": last};` then you can do `data: string`

Comment: You can stringify a JSON using JSON.stringify({name: name, last: last});

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
var name = 'Josh';
var last = 'Williams';

$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'ajax.php',
  data: {name:name,last:last}
});
```

The url will become:

```
ajax.php?name=Josh&last=Williams
```

Then, you can use those values using php, using `$_GET['name'] and $_GET['last']`

Answer (score 0):

```
var  formData = "name=ravi&age=31";  //Name value Pair
```

**or**

```
var formData = {name:"ravi",age:"31"}; //Array
```

**for this code example**

```
$.ajax({
    url : "AJAX_POST_URL",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //data - response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to try like this, i hope it can useful for you.

```
var name = 'Josh';
var last = 'Williams';

var string = 'name:'+name+', last:'+last';

$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'ajax.php',
  data: {string}
});
```